# How do I plot data points that are very close together in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Here's a sample of the three dataframe I'm working with. The full dataset contains 1,087 rows.

```
          Day Length  Category
1          1  33.807    Red
2          2  33.909    Red
3          3  34.011    Red
4          4  34.556    Red
5          5  34.789    Red
5          6  35        Red

          Day Length  Category
1          1  33.737    Blue
2          2  33.898    Blue
3          3  34.211    Blue
4          4  34.657    Blue
5          5  34.714    Blue
5          6  34.912    Blue

          Day Length  Category
1          1  33.631    Green
2          2  33.777    Green
3          3  34.101    Green
4          4  34.244    Green
5          5  34.590    Green
5          6  34.128    Green
```

My current code is as follows:

`ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Day, y = Length, group = Category)) + geom_line(aes(color = Category, alpha = 1), size = 2)`

But this results in three lines that are overlapping. Is there a better solution for this? Again, this dataset is a sample and the full dataset is much larger. So a solution that would work for a dataset of any size would be appreciated!

Comment: Please say more about "three lines that are overlapping." Are they three lines that sometimes cross, or they overlap perfectly so they look like one line (a plotting error)? Or is it a "readability" issue where it's not easy enough to tell them apart?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to focus on the difference, plot the difference:

```
dd = data.frame(Day = d1$Day, diff = d1$Length - d2$Length)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dd, aes(x = Day, y = diff)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, lwd = 1) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "Difference (first - second)")
```

### [image]

Using this data:

```
d1 = read.table(text = '          Day Length  
1          1  33.807
2          2  33.909
3          3  34.011
4          4  34.556
5          5  34.789
6          6  35', header = T)

d2 = read.table(text = '          Day Length  
1          1  33.737
2          2  33.898
3          3  34.211
4          4  34.657
5          5  34.714
6          6  34.912', header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical ggplot2 workflow would combine the two data sets into one table, with a column distinguishing the source, which you could then map to the color aesthetic, for instance. You might also add text labels if the distinction in the underlying data is important to show.

```
library(tidyverse)

tribble(
  ~Source, ~Day, ~Length,
"A",        1,  33.807,
"A",        2,  33.909,
"A",        3,  34.011,
"A",        4,  34.556,
"A",        5,  34.789,
"A",        6,  35,
"B",        1,  33.737,
"B",        2,  33.898,
"B",        3,  34.211,
"B",        4,  34.657,
"B",        5,  34.714,
"B",        6,  34.912) %>%
  
  ggplot(aes(Day, Length, color = Source)) +
  geom_line() +
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(aes(label = Length), 
                       direction = "y", box.padding = 0.5)
```

Or, if your data is in two tables like the `d1` and `d2` in the answer from @gregor-thomas, you could use something like this to combine them:

```
bind_rows("A" = d1, "B" = d2, .id = "Source") %>%
  ggplot(aes(Day, Length, color = Source)) +
  geom_line() +
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(aes(label = Length), 
                           direction = "y", box.padding = 0.5)
```

[image]

---

Edit:

If it's a visual readability issue, you might try variations like `ggshadow::geom_shadowline` to highlight overlaps:

```
devtools::install_github("marcmenem/ggshadow")
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(Day, Length, color = Category)) +
  ggshadow::geom_shadowline(size = 2)
```

[image]

Using this data:

```
df = read.table(text = 
'Day  Length   Category
1  33.807    Red
2  33.909    Red
3  34.011    Red
4  34.556    Red
5  34.789    Red
6  35        Red
1  33.737    Blue
2  33.898    Blue
3  34.211    Blue
4  34.657    Blue
5  34.714    Blue
6  34.912    Blue
1  33.631    Green
2  33.777    Green
3  34.101    Green
4  34.244    Green
5  34.590    Green
6  34.128    Green', header = T)
```

Comment: Is there a way to extend this to a dataset with 400 rows?

Comment: Tell me more. My immediate response is yes, you don't need to change anything, but maybe I'm not understanding what aspect concerns you. How to merge the data, how much space there is in the graph to show details, space enough for showing the text, or something else?

Comment: Yes, so what I showed only contained 6 days. If I have a dataset that contains 400 days worth of data, how would I go about creating a tribble the way you did? Hopefully that question makes sense. Thank you

Comment: The `tribble` function is a convenient way to input a data frame in a human-readable way, but if you already have two data frames you can use those instead, combining them with `bind_rows` like my 2nd example. https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/tribble.html.